# Twitter API: How to get All tweets from the twitter account in iphone App

Tags: iphone, twitter, integration

Using Twitter's Api system, I want to get all tweets(own tweet or other user do tweets on user profile) of a user account. However, this isn't really exactly what I wanted. As I am making an iPhone application, Since I am new to twitter integration its getting difficult for me to do the same. How to get all tweets(own tweet or other user do tweets on user profiles) from?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sample,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html

hope it will helps you......

Answer (score 0):

This can also help you.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

[This](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) will help you to get the Users Timeline(At max you can get upto 200 tweets in a single service)

A combination of the [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html) and twitter docs. It is so easy to integrate Twitter.